# Ace editor replace text

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor

I'm using `ui-ace`, I succeed to replace the selection text as the following:

```
$ace_editor.session.replace($ace_editor.selection.getRange(), "Hii");
```

But my problem is that this way don't update the ng-model, did I forget something to do?

Comment: are you using `ui-ace` ?

Comment: yes I'm using ui-ace

Comment: `ui-ace` might fail to trigger a digest loop to update `ngModel`. Try trigger a digest manually after you update the content, like `$scope.evalAsync(function () { // you code here } )`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Good man, thank you ... I put '$timeout' instead of 'evalAsync' and it worked perfect

Comment: cool. I put my solution to answer below as it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui-ace` will not update your the model for you then you need to trigger a digest loop yourself once you update the content in the editor.

A proper solution is use `evalAsync()` or `$timeout()` to wrap `$ace_editor.session.replace($ace_editor.selection.getRange(), "Hii");`.